# SmartGwt 2.4 with Maven on Eclipse

Tags: maven-2, smartgwt

Could Smartgwt 2.4 be usable with maven.
I take “Missing artifact com.smartgwt:smartgwt:jar:2.4:compile” error When give smartgwt version “2.4″. “2.0″ is ok but 2.2 and above gives error.

dependency;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

repo;

```
<repository>
   <id>smartclient</id>
   <name>smartclient.com</name>
   <url>http://www.smartclient.com/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the desired version of smartgwt.jar and smargwt-skins.jar and upload them to your own repository, such as nexus (http://nexus.sonatype.org/) and configure maven to use the resources from that repository as well.

Comment: Thanks I have also used as your description.